# Security in google apps script public HTMLService with new Utilities.getUuid() for each request

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, google-apps-script, web-applications

First question in stackoverflow in my life!

I am coming from the embedded programing world, and I have a very superficial knowledge on web security.
I have build a platform using **google apps script**. All the data are stored in datasheets. Everything works great.
I came up quickly with this authentication scheme, and honestly I am sure it must be un-secure! Definitely, I miss something! Here is my process:

1. Upon visiting the url (url shared via email - its a small community and it wont need a domain for that), the user is presented with a login form generated with HTMLService (doGet).
2. The form posts the data (doPost) and username & password are checked against values in a spreadsheet (TODO: hashing the passwords in future).
3. If matches, a UUID string is generated with a **Utilities.getUUID()** call. This string is stored in a spreadsheet.
4. Then the script generates and returns a **jQuery Mobile** website with **HTMLService**. All pages are served at once, as they use jQm pages navigation.

Here is the service call:

```
var addedContent = '<script>var session={sessionId="UUID"}</script>';
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile... ...addedContent(addedContent);
```

I use the .addedContent() call to append the UUID string as a javascript variable, which was generated with **Utilities.getUuid()** upon successful login.

5. Every subsequent call to the backend to get or set data happens with **google.script.run**. This always calls the same function, and passes and object with:

   - the actual function to be called,
   - the required data for the function,
   - the username and the latest UUID for every call.
6. First, the username and UUID are checked and if they match, then a new UUID is generated and stored in a spreadsheet.
7. Then the actual function is called and - together with the returned data - the UUID is send to the success handler:

Example of a function that will call google.script.run async:

```
function get_user(username){
  ...
  var session = {username: username, sessionId: lastUUID};
  // don't confuse the two username properties.
  // the username for the authentication is inside the session object.
  // the property 'username' of the data object is for the getUser function
  // which will be called in the server script. Also the "getUser" is not
  // the actual function name either: it will be switched with the real one.
  var data = {
    auth: session,
    action: "getUser",
    username: username
  };
  ...
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(get_user_success) 
    .withFailureHandler(get_user_failure)
    .switchboard(data);`
}
```

In the server:

```
function switchboard(data){
  var result = {sessionId: false};
  var action = data["action"];
  //
  var auth = authenticate(data["auth"]);
  // authenticate returns the new uuid string upon match or
  // deletes previous uuid and returns false
  if (auth == false) return result;
  switch(action){
    ...
    case 'getUser': response = the_real_function_name(data); break;
    ...
  }
  result = { sessionId: auth, response: response };
  return result;
  // so, what the page gets back is and object with the new uuid string
  // for the next call, and the actual requested data
}
```

Upon success:

```
function get_user_success(data){
  // data = {sessionId: "uuidstring", data: obj}
  sessionId = data["sessionId"] // new uuid string for subsequent calls
  ...
  $("some#element").val(data["data"]["address"]);
}
```

8. If for some reason the previous UUID does not match, then it is deleted and then the user asked to login again.

Although I believe that with this scheme I am protected against the stupidity or curiosity of the community members (after all they are busy dentists and they need this working!) what I fear are attacks in the case the url leaks. I have considered using google or facebook connect APIs but it is not feasable for other reasons.
Does HTTPS guarantees the security of this scheme?
Is there a huge and embarrassing hole in my implementation?

P.S. I tried to search here and elsewhere for a solution, but all I can find is the opposite: how can google apps script authenticate to a third server - I can't find a solution where someone serves a GAS webapp with anonymous execution rights and authentication.